# Unable to animate results. saveMovie function not found

Tags: r

Unable to find saveMovie function in R.
Continuously getting the following error.

```
saveMovie(animate_plot(), interval = 0.1, outdir = getwd())
```

> ```
> Error in saveMovie(animate_plot(), interval = 0.1, outdir = getwd()) : 
>   could not find function "saveMovie"
> ```

Comment: So did you `library(animation)`?

Comment: Try `animation:::saveMovie` instead of just `saveMovie`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg strangely enough, `saveMovie` is documented but apparently not exported.